# How to fit image in parent block div?

Tags: html, css

There is a code with image and wrapper:

```
<div #container id="container" [style.transform]="transform$ | async">
        <img
        #image
        class="image"
      />
```

I have tried this:

```
#container{
   height: 500px
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 
}
```

But image is distorted

Comment: Maybe better apply transform image using JS depends parent height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you set both, `width` **and** `height` to 100%. Then the image will look distorted.

You have to set:

- only `width: 100%;` or
- only `height: 100%;`.

If you set only one of them to 100%, the image will be proportionally smaller/bigger and won't be distorted.

But there's a downside. It means that the image will not fill the container.